# Crack the Caesar cipher

Tags: code-golf, string, cipher

The Caesar cipher is a simple and famous cipher, where the letters of the alphabet are rotated by some secret amount. For example, if our secret rotation is `3`, we would replace `a` with `d`, `b` with `e`, `w` with `z`, `x` with `a` and so on.

Here is an example (rotation amount: 10):

```
Robo sc kx ohkwzvo
```

This cipher is very weak, because short common English words like "I", "a", "is", "an", "if", etc. are easy to detect. Your task is to crack a Caesar cipher, that is, recover the rotation amount from the ciphertext. As additional input, you are given a list (or set) of words, which the plaintext can contain. It is guaranteed that there is only one answer.

## Examples

```
"Ifmmp Xpsme!", ["world", "banana", "hello"]
-> 1

"Nc cd, Kadcn?", ["cogito", "et", "ergo", "tu", "sum", "brute"]
-> 9

"boring", ["boring"]
-> 0

"bccb foo", ["abba", "gpp", "cddc"]
-> 25

" !\"#$%&'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\\]^_`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{|}~", ["zabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxy"]
-> 1

"bcsbdbebcsb", ["abracadabra", "za", "aq"]
-> 1
```

## IO rules

The ciphertext can contain any printable ascii characters. The dictionary (list of words) contains strings made of lowercase letters (a-z). Words are separated by non-letters. Only letters are rotated (punctuation is ignored). You will output an integer in the range `[0,25]`

Comment: Would outputting in the range `[1,26]` instead be acceptable (this is currently prohibited by your rules)?

Comment: @JonathanAllan I've decided against it, since [0,25] is a more natural range

Comment: Can you take the ciphertext as an array of words?

Comment: @Jonah No, the annoying string processing is a part of this challenge

Comment: Suggested test-case (that my currently deleted post would fail with, yet pass all others): `"bcsbdbebcsb", ["abracadabra", "za", "aq"] -> 1`. If one looks for substrings of rotated words in the text, ignoring the fact that it is only one word long, then rotating `2` will give two matching substrings, while rotating `1` will only give one matching substring.

Comment: Why "!..."..." I think you need "!...\"..."

Answer (score 6):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 66 bytes

Curried function that takes the dictionary first and the ciphertext second.

```
->w{f=->s{s=~/^([^a-z]|#{w*?|})*$/i?0:1+f[s.tr'a-zA-Z','ZA-Y'*2]}}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72kqDSpcsGidNulpSVpuhY3nXTtyqvTbHXtiquLbev04zSi4xJ1q2JrlKvLtexrajW1VPQz7Q2sDLXToov1SorUgZKOulHqOupRjrqR6lpGsbW1UJOOFpSWFCukR0crlecX5aQo6SgoJSXmASGIlZGak5OvFBsbreSZlptboBBRUJybqqgUywXXlJyfnlmSD1KbWgImi9LBvJJSEFlcmgs2sKi0JBVsjF-yQnKKjoJ3Ykpynj2yOUn5RZl56WA1MCZCMjEpCeyc9IICEJWckpIMUZmcnKSQlg90IcQzCxZAaAA)

From the dictionary a regex can be generated that only matches decoded text:

```
irb> w
=> ["world", "banana", "hello"]
irb> /^([^a-z]|#{w*?|})*$/i
=> /^([^a-z]|world|banana|hello)*$/i
```

Answer (score 4):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 99 bytes

*Saved 1 byte thanks to @l4m2*

Expects `(string)(dictionary)`, where the dictionary is a set.

```javascript
s=>g=(d,k=25)=>s.match(/[a-z]+/gi).some(s=>!d.has(Buffer(s).map(c=>(c%32+k)%26+97)+''))&&1+g(d,k-1)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hdBNS8MwGAfwu58iC2xL6JutTNkhFbyJ4MWLMHZIn7y0rmlKkzrwy9e2etnm8AnkjYffP@SDf3IHXdX6qLFCDooNjuWaEREeWLahLHex4R5Kkux49LUPEl3R2Fkjydi3EHHJHXnqlZIdcXRsbQmwnMDyLgsOdJndB9sHGqzXlK5WaaAnNkrpALZxtpZxbTUJFMHPypgWvbfOyAWmpJFH9CY92eGj7WqBQ4QL3oxj2pWyri3eU0rRH5UkKL05518BgQjRCxfQPJ74YHXl7cRKP8@dnk@@n2bXmzm76738SRz57QVf2K5q9In7e3Xtlddq5G8veYACKWtPAnhRzL@h23ZaQAj4P23ks83wDQ)

Comment: `(c|32)` => `c%32` with some other changes?

Comment: @l4m2 Initializing `k` to `25`? Or maybe there's a better way.

Answer (score 2):

## [Vyxal 2.4.1](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 19 bytes

```
λ?⇩⌈Ǎka:nǓ$vĿ?vcA;ṅ
```

[Try it Online!](https://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=&code=%CE%BB%3F%E2%87%A9%E2%8C%88%C7%8Dka%3An%C7%93%24v%C4%BF%3FvcA%3B%E1%B9%85&inputs=%22bccb%22%0A%5B%22bccb%22%2C%20%22gpp%22%2C%20%22cddc%22%5D&header=&footer=)

Basically, try a cipher of each rotation and output the rotation number where all the words are in the dictionary.

2 can play at the legacy version saving bytes game.

### Explained

```
λ?⇩⌈Ǎka:nǓ$vĿ?vcA;ṅ
λ                ;ṅ   # Find the first integer n, such that
 ?⇩                   #   the lowercase input
   ⌈                   #   split on spaces
    Ǎ                 #    and with all non-alphabet letters removed
             ?vcA     #    contains all words from the input after
           vĿ         #    being transliterated according to the mapping:
     ka:nǓ$           #      lowercase alphabet → lowercase alphabet rotated left n times
```

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E (legacy)](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/tree/fb4a2ce2bce6660e1a680a74dd61b72c945e6c3b), <s>19</s> 18 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
[DIlÐáмS¡åP#ADÀ‡}N
```

First input is the list of words, second the sentence.

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f8/2sUz5/CEwwsv7Ak@tPDw0gBlR5fDDY8aFtb6AeWUkvPTM0vylXQUlFJLwGRROphXUgoii0tzQVRSUWlJqlIsl1@yQnKKjoJ3Ykpynj0A) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/V9Waa@k8KhtkoKSfWVC6P9ol4icwxMOL7ywJ/jQwsNLA5QdXQ43PGpYWOv3X@d/dHS0Unl@UU6Kko5SUmIeEAIZGak5OflKsTpKnmm5uQUKEQXFuamKQL4CUHFyfnpmST5QUWoJiChKB7FLSoFEcWkuyJCi0pJUkF6/ZIXkFB0F78SU5Dx7qOak/KLMvHSQLJwFEk5MSgJZm15QACSTU1KSwSqSk5MU0vKB7ogFAA).

Uses the legacy version of 05AB1E because of three reasons, each saving a single byte:

1. `‡` works on a list of strings, whereas the new version requires a map around it - `ADÀ‡}` would have been `εADÀ‡]` in that case;
2. `N` outputs the last index outside of a loop, whereas this is just `0` in the new version and we would have to use the counter variable - `N` would have been `¾`, and `¼` would have to be added after the `#`;
3. `¡` in the new version would keep empty strings as items, and we would have to remove them - so an additional `á` would have to be added after the `¡` to only keep the words.

**Explanation:**

```python
[         # Loop indefinitely:
 D        #  Duplicate the current list
          #  (which will be the first implicit input-list in the first iteration)
  I       #  Push the second input-sentence
   l      #  Convert it to lowercase
    Ð     #  Triplicate it
     á    #  Only leave the letters of the top copy
      м   #  Remove all those letters from the second copy
       S  #  Convert the non-letters to a list of characters
        ¡ #  Split the lowercase sentence on these non-letters
  å       #  Check for each word if it's in the list
   P      #  Check if this is truthy for all of them
    #     #  If it is: stop the infinite loop
  ADÀ‡    #  Caesar Cipher the words in the list once:
  A       #   Push the lowercase alphabet: "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
   DÀ     #   Duplicate, and rotated once: "bcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyza"
     ‡    #   Transliterate the words in the list
}N        # After the loop: push the last 0-based index
          # (which is output implicitly as result)
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Retina 0.8.2](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language/a950ad7d925ec9316e3e2fb2cf5d49fd15d23e3d), 83 bytes

```
T`L`l
[^a-z¶]+
@
^
¶
{ms`\A(#*)¶@?((\w+\b)(?=.*¶\3$)@?)+$.*
$.1
^\B
#
T`l`zl`^.*¶.*
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Fco9CsIwAAbQ/TtFoR2SVAPiLKmuilM3Y0ibhlLoD6QpQr1XDpCLRXzzc9YPc5NSrR96xEs1xz2Gd4kKCjHgO61aXknOaAyVIER@StlSIi6cxSDPBa0ELQvOUPATlLwhR61HvY9a/QdnKT1NZrpDdm86MwuYpR/8AuthXb/Ab1i3Ca3bvP0B) Takes input as a line of ciphertext followed by each dictionary entry on a separate line. Explanation:

```
T`L`l
```

Lowercase everything.

```
[^a-z¶]+
@
```

Change non-letters to a marker to simplify matching.

```
^
¶
```

Prepend a blank line to hold the result.

```
{`
```

Repeat until the result is found.

```
ms`\A(#*)¶@?((\w+\b)(?=.*¶\3$)@?)+$.*
$.1
```

If all the words in the ciphertext are in the dictionary then replace the whole buffer with the result.

```
^\B
#
```

If the result has not been found then increment the rotation amount.

```
T`l`zl`^.*¶.*
```

If the ciphertext is still present then rotate it.

Answer (score 2):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>99</s> 103 bytes

*Edit: Thanks to pajonk for bug-spotting, which unfortunately cost +4 bytes (also thanks to pajonk)*

```r
f=function(x,d)`if`(all(x%in%d),0,1+f(gsub("[^a-z]","",chartr("a-zA-Z","za-za-y",scan(t=x,,x))),d))%%26
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hVDZVtswEH3nKxSlLhLIJQl7S1haaFkK3dgKgUaL7bjYkpFlMKbw68FySpqH9HB0zszV6N6rmdF9rQw1oZLtvt/2M8ktRjkRuBv6XUSjCOVOKB2BSYM0p30UpBlD8PySusUFJBAS3qPaaATLwoZ7VpaKElH3DpKUU4lMOyckxxiXlthxWgvDHxHc8eM4AadJGns1SABH8FbpSJQQMirLY1HPiyIFMQZ14K6C5sQ/@QEHXBCwRwWXawM9V0FolJV5poo6qG4mszHN4spbZ8YbOi6PODKlQxkMrP7iZ1pjlMY5A75SAyJlrGo0SBKbuBB8qGrNj8hArQPrr5zXkwhPTRP3zUyj2Zqdm19YXFp@@26lvbq2vvH@w@bWx0/bO7t7n/cPvnz99v3H4dHxyenPs/NO5wLUL391KePC84Ne@PsqiqVKrnVqspvb/K64//PwOOio@C9p7B4ZT5lgnk3PE2nKqbDJTlRUkV6PF1drqr24M6kMGLNeYh9GBP0n)

Comment: I guess this fails in many cases when the output should be `0`: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TU1LCsIwEN17ijhSmMEJ1ANU8BqK0jQlNVASSFOIvXxMQa27938hBx9VtN412TRmdnrFmLin1poW1ThiqqyreuKaT0eDwzR3CLeHkssdGID1U4UYEIpwkdciLQUp@QKetHIYm8SciKhM0u8NofPBumEPLPSXAJE4CHkW9W7LOR/Fx/6P8mpshfwG "R – Try It Online")

Comment: [Quick-fix for +4](https://tio.run/##hVDZVtswEH3nKxSlLhLIJQl7S1haaFkK3dgKgUaL7bjYkpFlMKbw68FySpqH9HB0zszV6N6rmdF9rQw1oZLtvt/2M8ktRjkRuBv6XUSjCOVOKB2BSYM0p30UpBlD8PySusUFJBAS3qPaaATLwoZ7VpaKElH3DpKUU4lMOyckxxiXlthxWgvDHxHc8eM4AadJGns1SABH8FbpSJQQMirLY1HPiyIFMQZ14K6C5sQ/@QEHXBCwRwWXawM9V0FolJV5poo6qG4mszHN4spbZ8YbOi6PODKlQxkMrP7iZ1pjlMY5A75SAyJlrGo0SBKbuBB8qGrNj8hArQPrr5zXkwhPTRP3zUyj2Zqdm19YXFp@@26lvbq2vvH@w@bWx0/bO7t7n/cPvnz99v3H4dHxyenPs/NO5wLUL391KePC84Ne@PsqiqVKrnVqspvb/K64//PwOOio@C9p7B4ZT5lgnk3PE2nKqbDJTlRUkV6PF1drqr24M6kMGLNeYh9GBP0n "R – Try It Online")

Comment: @pajonk - Ah, thanks for spotting, I didn't think of that.

Answer (score 1):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 132 bytes

```javascript
y=>f=x=>eval(`/(?<![a-z])(?!${y}(?![a-z]))[a-z]/i`).test(x)&&f(x.replace(/[a-z]/ig,t=>(t=parseInt(t,36)-1,t-9?t:35).toString(36)))+1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LYvLasMwEEV/xTElmaGyTQgt9CF7FyiFbroMAavyRCi4kpHGwenj213HzeYcLod7VCcVdbAdZ843NG7leJblQQ6ypJNqoS6gel7sVPa1R6gWN9/n30n/G2cVtsacKTIMuFweYMgDda3SBMW1G8GyBJadCpFeHAOLzT1ma8HZQ8WPm7vp7985WGdgCoi36/FJexd9S3nrDWxhl2pvLPtUJCnxzGDmxf2Fsf@86CP0TOk@P3rr6p8aYfWmE92I5FU12lUrxPEP)

As always, long part adding 1 to letter

Comment: I think digits and `_` may appear in the input string, making the code fail.

Comment: @Arnauld The point is that I don't remember what `\w` match

Answer (score 0):

## [Python](https://www.python.org), 120 bytes

```
f=lambda s,d,t=-1:~-any([chr((ord(c)%32+t)%26+97)for c in w]in d for w in re.findall(r'\w+',s))and-~f(s,d,~-t)
import re
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=XZBNasMwEIX3OcUgCJFqqdAU-gehBwj0Ao4XimQlAlsy4xFONj5D991kk96pt2nk_lC6ecNjZr43zNt7d6R9DKfTOZFTDx8Ht2p0u7UaemklrdTN06h0OPLS7JHziJYbMb9dFiTmy7vi8V64iGDABxiqi1jIfsge62vng9VNw3GxGYqF7IXQwarR8QwfFYmZb7uIdJn9zn_t0AfijrMXA8ZKWGtrwjOT5VWrO974nmTJTNx5ikwCq2lS3E2OUtY-tblsMVHNKlEJMful1gSUJEy9_9TMmhB_V7_u-vnPJw)